# Numpad0 not working with char.IsLetterOrDigit

Tags: c#, onkeyup

I have a method that I call when a the KeyUp event fires on my control and within that method I check the key pressed is a letter or digit using the char.IsLetterOrDigit method. However it doesn't seem to work with the KeyPad numbers!?

My code is below:

```
    void MyControls_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((char.IsLetterOrDigit(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue))))
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

Anybody any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using C#4.0

Comment: Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue) is not a method for getting the character for a key event. It is only by coincidence that it works for the top row numbers. Why are you doing this on the KeyUp event instead of KeyPress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing what you think you're doing.

`Convert.ToChar()` isn't going to take a keyboard code and turn it into the character that that key represents; there's too much involved in doing this, what with different keyboard layouts, cultures, key modifier states, and so on.  What you're doing here is taking the *numeric value of the KeyCode enumeration* and casting it to `char`.

If you want to retrieve the character associated with a key press, you need to override the `KeyPress` event rather than the `KeyUp` event.  Windows Forms will do all of the necessary translation and conversion in order to determine which character corresponds to the key.

Answer (score 1):

KeyUp lets you take care of all buttons on the keyboard (including special keys like Function and the number pad).  However, the KeyValue or KeyCode don't always refer to the character of the button pushed.

KeyPress will give you the character of the button pushed, but will not deal with special keys (including the number pad when numlock is off).

If you want to deal with ALL keys on a keyboard, I'd use KeyUp. e.KeyValue returns the values in the Keys enum (so numberpad 0 is Keys.NumPad0), if you just want to deal with entered values, use KeyPress.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
        {
            // your code
        }
        // else for other numpad keys
```